# How do I create files in directory owned by user in same group without sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo, access-control-list, www-data

I have created a user to own website files (drupal) and added that user to www-data, so essentially all files are drupaluser:www-data. I want to go in and put the site in to git but I get permission denied although we are both members of www-data. I could switch to that user - ask user for password, sudo su which would mean that all files created would be owned by root until i set permissions again on the directory structure.

Is there a way that I can work in that directory, add the files to a git repo without having to reset directory permissions. Is this where an acl might be used?

Comment: You might try `sudo su drupaluser`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `sudo su drupaluser` and check out `man su`.